# adding jira visual studio connector

Tags: visual-studio, jira, jira-plugin

I just installed the JIRA connector for VS2010 and having a strange problem adding my JIRA server to the "Add server" settings of the configurations.
The plugin throws 404 error for the server address that I give. 
http://x.x.x.x:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa

but otherwise I can browse this link to access JIRA.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting of accepting REMOTE API calls was OFF in Global Configurations.
When I turned it on, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting just `http://x.x.x.x:8080` as your server instead?

Comment: I fixed it by turning on remote API calls. Thanks anyway! :)